# Cannot work out why i cannot find member name and name channel

Tags: discord.js

using the code below i keep getting errors saying cannot find name 'member' and name 'channel' any help would be lovely also if you see any other issues thanks :)

```js
import DiscordJS, { Guild, Intents, Message, GuildMember } from 'discord.js'
import dotenv from 'dotenv'
dotenv.config()

const client = new DiscordJS.Client({
    intents: [
        Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS,
        Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES,
        Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGE_REACTIONS,
        Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MEMBERS
    ]
})

client.on('ready', ()=>{
    console.log('Santa is coming')
    const CF = Boolean(member.guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === 'welcome'))
    if (CF == true){
        console.log('Found it!')
    }
})

client.on('messageCreate', (message) =>{
    if (message.content == 'santa?'){
        message.react('')
        message.reply({
            content: "HO, HO, HO, I'll be coming soon!"
        })
    }
})

client.login(process.env.TOKEN)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### On v13.2.0 :

```js
const CF = Boolean(member.guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === 'welcome'))
```

Here you put `member` which you didn't define yet.
Use `client.channels.fetch` instead

```js
const CF = Boolean(client.channels.fetch(<id of the channel>))
```

Comment: No problem, if this answer fixed your problem you can confirm it with the big "check mark" <3

Comment: now im getting name doesnt exist on channel

Comment: Can you give me your discord.js version and node.js version to be sure what I said works (they're on your package.json file I think)

Comment: discord.js is 13.2 and node.js is 16.11.1

Comment: No problem I love to help, if you have any problem ask another question ^^